# Filename formatting in Python under Windows

Tags: python, unicode, codepages, mbcs

I have two distincts files called:

> '╠.txt'  and  '¦.txt'

Such simple code:

```
files = os.listdir('E:\pub\private\desktop\')
for f in files:
    print f, repr(f), type (f)
```

which would return

```
¦.txt '\xa6.txt' <type 'str'>
¦.txt '\xa6.txt' <type 'str'>
```

I don't get why I am getting the code 0xA6 for the ╠ character instead of OxCC.
I have been trying to play arround with the encode-decode methode but without success.
I have noticed that sys.getfilesystemencoding() is set mbcs - but I can't manage to change it something like cp437.

Any help is very much appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: OT for your actual question, but when working with paths on Windows, do one of (1) use raw strings `r"E:\whatever"` (2) use forward slashes `"E:/whatever"` (3) double the backslashes `"E:\\whatever"` to avoid another question here when your paths get interpreted wrong because your string literal contains a `\n`, `\t` or another character like that.

Comment: Using Python 3, with `sys.getfilesystemencoding()` returning `'mbcs'`, I don't seem to be encountering your problem. @bgporter: Yeah, the way he has it set up it looks like the string is never closed properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to pass a unicode string to `os.listdir` and Python will return unicode filenames:

```
# a string that is unicode+raw (escapes \)
path = ur"E:\pub\private\desktop"
print os.listdir(path)
# [u'\xa6.txt', u'\u2560.txt']
```

Windows NT actually uses unicode for filenames, but I guess Python tries to encode them when you pass a encoded path name.

Comment: This was indeed the issue-

Code as follow now fixes my mojibake :-
    path = ur"E:\pub\private\desktop\TestMp3"
    files = os.listdir(path)
    for f in files:
        print f, repr(f), type (f)
        msdos = f.encode('cp437')
        sjis = msdos.decode('shift-jis')
        print f, repr(sjis), sjis


Tks a  lot -